# Cannot build and run an application using Yeoman

Tags: node.js, angularjs, yeoman-generator

I have done an application using Angular js and I am trying to build it with yeoman.

I have done the following steps:

1. npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower
2. npm install -g generator-angular
3. yo angular
4. In .bowerecc file,

   {
     "directory": "app/components",
     "json": "bower.json" // Add this line
   }
5. bower install angular-bootstrap --save
6. grunt server

After this,

```
>> Local Npm module "grunt-karma" not found. Is it installed?
Warning: Task "watch" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Then I did `npm install grunt-karma` but got

```
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\584042\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs\node_modules\grunt requires async@'~0.1.22' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\584042\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs\node_modules\async,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.2.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package bower does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-bower-requirejs@0.4.4 wants bower@~0.x
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer yo@1.1.2 wants bower@>=0.9.0

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Users\\584042\\Documents\\tools\\nodejs\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\584042\\Documents\\tools\\nodejs\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.j
"generator-angular"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\584042\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.7
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\584042\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Please Advice

Comment: It tested `generator-angular` and its broken (both on linux and windows)

Comment: I get the same damn thing